# How to make a PowerShell argument completer that only suggests files not already selected?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, tab-completion, powershell-7.3

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this so going to first explain what I want to happen.

my PowerShell module function has this parameter

```
[ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf })][ValidatePattern("\.xml$")][parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string[]]$PolicyPaths,
```

It accepts multiple `.xml` files.

I've been using this argument completer for it:

```
$ArgumentCompleterPolicyPaths = {
    Get-ChildItem | where-object { $_.extension -like '*.xml' } | foreach-object { return "`"$_`"" }
}
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName "Deploy-SignedWDACConfig" -ParameterName "PolicyPaths" -ScriptBlock $ArgumentCompleterPolicyPaths
```

It's been working fine. Now I want to improved it so that when I need to select multiple `.xml` files from the current working directory, and start selecting them by pressing Tab (without typing anything because I don't know the file names), the suggested files don't contain the ones I've already selected. The way I select them is by pressing Tab first and after each selected file, add a comma `,` and then press Tab again to select another from the suggestions.

I've tried 2 new argument completers but none of them work the way I want.

here is the first one:

```
$ArgumentCompleterPolicyPaths = {
  # Get the current command and the already bound parameters
  param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters)
  # Get the xml files in the current directory
  Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Extension -like '*.xml' } | ForEach-Object {
    # Check if the file is already selected
    if ($fakeBoundParameters.PolicyPaths -notcontains $_.FullName) {
      # Return the file name with quotes
      return "`"$_`""
    }
  }
}
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName "Deploy-SignedWDACConfig" -ParameterName "PolicyPaths" -ScriptBlock $ArgumentCompleterPolicyPaths
```

and here is the second one:

```
# Define a class that inherits from ArgumentCompleterAttribute
class XmlFileCompleter : ArgumentCompleterAttribute {
  # Override the GetArgumentCompletionSuggestions method
  [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]] GetArgumentCompletionSuggestions(
    [System.Management.Automation.CommandAst]$commandAst,
    [System.Management.Automation.CommandParameterAst]$parameterAst,
    [System.Collections.IDictionary]$fakeBoundParameters,
    [System.Management.Automation.Language.IScriptPosition]$cursorPosition
  ) {
    # Get all XML files in the current directory
    $xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.xml
    # Filter out the files that have already been selected
    $xmlFiles = $xmlFiles | Where-Object { $fakeBoundParameters[$parameterAst.ParameterName] -notcontains $_.Name }
    # Return the file names as completion results
    foreach ($xmlFile in $xmlFiles) {
      [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($xmlFile.Name, $xmlFile.Name, 'ParameterValue', $xmlFile.Name)
    }
  }
}
```

The last throws this error in VS code:

```
Unable to find type [ArgumentCompleterAttribute].
```

P.S This is current behavior with my argument tab completer, see how it suggests the same file that I already selected:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtCaUNAJbbvIhupw8-67jn6ScaBOGw?e=a35FoG

it's APNG file so just drag n drop it on a browser.

Comment: What is the dollar sign after xml used for? [ValidatePattern("\.xml$")]

Comment: Anchor for the end of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem is that the dictionary of provisionally bound parameters, `$fakeBoundParameters`, only contains information about *other* parameters *if you haven't typed a prefix of a non-initial array element to be completed*.

  - That is, with `el1` and `el2` representing previously typed / tab-completed array elements, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `el1, el2,`  causes the parameter at hand *not* to be included as an entry in `$fakeBoundParameters`, so that the `el1` and `el2` values cannot be examined that way.

    - This is due to a bug / design limitation of the `$fakeBoundParameter` dictionary passed to argument-completers, up to at least PowerShell 7.4.0-preview.3: a *syntactically incomplete* expression such as `el1, el2,` seemingly prevents inclusion of the array elements provided so far; see [GitHub issue #17975](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17975)
  - Therefore, for an array parameter being tab-completed *without having typed at least one character at the start of the new element*, any array elements *previously* typed / completed are in effect *not* reflected in `$fakeBoundParameters`.
- The **workaround** is to search the command AST passed reflected in the `$commandAst` completer script-block for string-constant expressions that end end in `.xml`, as shown below:

  - Note:

    - At least hypothetically, this could yield false positives, namely if *other* parameters too accept strings ending in `.xml`
    - As in your own attempt, what the user has manually typed before attempting tab-completion of a given array element is *not* considered; doing so would require more work.

```bash
Register-ArgumentCompleter `
  -CommandName Deploy-SignedWDACConfig `
  -ParameterName PolicyPaths `
  -ScriptBlock {
    # Get the current command and the already bound parameters
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters)

    # Find all string constants in the AST that end in ".xml"
    $existing = $commandAst.FindAll({ 
        $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst] -and 
        $args[0].Value -like '*.xml' 
      }, 
      $false
    ).Value  

    # Get the xml files in the current directory
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xml | ForEach-Object {
      # Check if the file is already selected
      if ($_.FullName -notin $existing) {
        # Return the file name with quotes
        "`"$_`""
      }
    }
  }
```

---

As for your attempt to use [`ArgumentCompleterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute):

- You got an error, because you didn't use the *full* type name as the base class name in your [custom `class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) definition, `System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute`

  - Curiously, however, *omitting* the `Attribute` suffix, i.e. `ArgumentCompleter` *does* seem to work without a namespace qualifier.
- That said, instead of *sub-classing* this `ArgumentCompleter`, you could simply use it *directly*,  passing the same script block you used with `Register-ArgumentCompleter` as an attribute property; that is, inside your `Deploy-SignedWDACConfig` command, you can decorate the `$PolicyPaths` parameter declaration with `[ArgumentCompleter({ ... })]`.

Comment: Thank you for the script and info on the other attempt, that works perfectly! looking at my module I don't think I have cases where 2 parameters need `xml` on the same cmdlet, but if that happens I hope it won't be too hard to fix that case . :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SpyNet; my pleasure. Re handling two parameters that accept `.xml` paths: it won't be trivial, unfortunately (you'd need to both recognize parameter names and infer positional arguments), but we can cross that bridge when we get to it; if so, I encourage you to ask a new question that builds on this one.

Comment: Of course ^^ I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76143006/how-to-prevent-powershell-validateset-argument-completer-from-suggesting-the-sam) but this time I want to apply the same concept on a class-based validateSet argument completer.

Comment: Thank you, I see the workaround is already implemented in your answer and it's been working really well so far!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SpyNet. When i originally implemented the workaround, the stated reason for why it was needed to begin with wasn't quite correct; the later update I notified you of corrected that.